# Format Python timestamp for Teradata DB table

Tags: python, datetime, teradata

I am working with a Teradata table that has a timestamp column: TIMESTAMP(6) with data that looks like this:

```
2/14/2019 13:09:51.210000
```

Currently I have a Python time variable that I want to send into the Teradata table via SQL, that looks like below:

```
from datetime import datetime

time = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

02/14/2019 13:23:24
```

How can I reformat that to insert correctly?  It is error'ing out with:

```
teradata.api.DatabaseError: (6760, '[22008] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-6760)Invalid timestamp.')
```

I tried using the same format the Teradata timestamp column uses:

```
time = datetime.now().strftime("%mm/%dd/%YYYY %HH24:%MI:%SS")
```

Same error message

Thanks

Comment: m-d-y might be a client format, try `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` instead.

Comment: @dnoeth thanks, but that didn't work either unfortunately.  Same error.

Comment: Then try to pass the string as-is and apply a Teradata function: `To_Timestamp('02/14/2019 13:23:24', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` or switch to a Standard SQL timestamp literal: `TIMESTAMP 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Turned out to be unrelated to the timestamp, and I had to reformat the DataFrame column it was being read from.  Changing the Data Type fixed it:

```
final_result_set['RECORD_INSERTED'] = pd.to_datetime(final_result_set['RECORD_INSERTED'])
```

Now when looping through and inserting via SQL, the following worked fine for populating 'RECORD_INSERTED':

```
time = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Sorry for the confusion